# setTimeout и цикл for - каков порядок выполнения?

Tags: javascript, функции

```
var count = 0;
for ( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
    setTimeout(
        function(){ 
            assert( i == count++, "Check the value of i." );
        },
        i * 200);
}
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, как работает этот код. Почему цикл бегает четыре раза со значением 4?

Comment: @setback, чёто я никогда не слышал о ф-ции `assert` в JS. Что она делает, поясните...

Comment: Я понимаю что сперва запускается цикл, бегает до значения четыре, потом запускается setTimeout. Но почему так? Может кто-то ссылку подкинет какую почитать..?

Comment: @Rules возможно потому что это собственная функция?)

Comment: потому как i копируется по ссылке и через 200 мс цикл точно завершиться.

     assert( i == count++, "Check the value of i." );

выполняется уже не в цикле.

Comment: @Rules имеется ввиду [console.assert](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114483/)

Comment: @Rules, функция тут не причем. Автор, вам нужно использовать замыкания.

Comment: @setback, Вы похоже неверно понимаете назначение setTimeout, это не sleep

Comment: >@Rules имеется ввиду console.assert

А... Спасибо!, буду знать :)

Comment: Спасибо всем. Думаю что мне надо разобраться как работает setTimeout... 
a `assert` самописная функция,подсмотрел на stackoverflow - не знал тогда про console.assert - тот же самый принцип..
function assert(expression, description) {
    var message = expression ? 'PASS' : 'FAIL';
    console.log(message + ': ' + description);
}

Comment: @lampa: замыкания ТС как раз и использует (по переменной `i`), разве нет? Ему нужно использовать их [_правильно_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555464/javascript-closure-of-loop).

Comment: @VladD правильно это и означает, что их нужно использовать :) Я же не вижу этого в скрипте.

Comment: @VladD всё правильно говорит, переменная `i` находится в замыкании по отношении к функции, которая передана в `setTimeout`

Answer (score 3):

Проблема с обработчиками в цикле

Comment: Закрыть как повтор?

+1.

Comment: спорный вопрос, с одной стороны тема вопроса аналогичная - цикл и асинхронные функции, с другой - это не так уж и очевидно

Answer (score 3):

[демо](http://jsfiddle.net/zBPvu/)

Сам setTimeOut работает асинхронно, то есть вне запускается 4 раза на выполнение функция assert i у Вас глобальная переменная и во время выполнения функции assert она уже равна 4 ем. Цикл пробегает быстрее.

[явная демонстрация сего факта](http://jsfiddle.net/uYuqT/) сначало цикл прошел потом сработали assert ы